# Fourier Transform Time Scaling

Tags: transform, fourier

I edited the initial question to make it general and thus applicable in more situations.

If the Fourier Transform of $x(t^2)$ is some function of $\omega^2$. Then what is the Fourier Transform of $x(bt^2)$, for $b>0$?

Is it $\dfrac{1}{b}$ times a function of $\left(\dfrac{\omega}{b}\right)^2$, or $\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\right)$ times a function of $\left( \dfrac{\omega}{\sqrt{b}} \right)^2$, or neither?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: i wasn't the one who down-arrowed this question, but Over needs to pose it in a manner that isn't made up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y(t) = x(t^2)$, and $a$ be such that:

$$
\begin{align}
  y(at) 
   &= x((at)^2) \\
   &= x(a^2t^2) \\
   &= x(bt^2)
\end{align}
$$
In other words, $a^2 = b$.

The Fourier Transform time-scaling property states that given the Fourier Transform pair:
$$
\begin{align}
  y(t) \leftrightarrow Y(w)
\end{align}
$$
and $a>0$, we have the relation:
$$
\begin{align}
  y(at) &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a}Y(\frac{w}{a})
\end{align}
$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
  x(bt^2) &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a}Y(\frac{w}{a}) \\
          &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}Y(\frac{w}{\sqrt{b}})
\end{align}
$$

Now, if we define
$$
\begin{align}
Y(w) = G(w^2)
\end{align}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
Y(w/a) &= G(w^2/a^2) \\
Y(\frac{w}{\sqrt{b}}) &= G(\frac{w^2}{b})
\end{align}
$$

Yielding,
$$
\begin{align}
x(bt^2) &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a}Y(\frac{w}{a}) \\
        &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}G(\frac{w^2}{b}) \\
        &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}G((\frac{w}{\sqrt{b}})^2)
\end{align}
$$
Or, in prose (1/sqrt(b)) times a function of (w/sqrt(b))^2.

Answer (score 0):

If $x(t)$ is a time signal, then its Fourier transform can be taken to be
$$X(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) \exp(-j2\pi ft)\,\mathrm dt.$$
But what is *meant* by $x(t)$? Well, $x(t)$ is a real function of a real
variable $t$ by which is meant that for each (real number) value of $t$, 
the *function* $x(\cdot)$ assigns a real number that we denote by $x(t)$.
Usually, $x(t)$ is described by a *formula* such as
$x(t) = \exp(-\pi |t|)$ which says in words that we

> take the absolute value of whatever is inside the parentheses, multiply it
>   by $-\pi$ and raise $e$ to the result of the multiplication.

With this, we consider the function $y(t)$ whose value at any $t$
is defined to be the value of $x(t^2)$ where $x(t)$
happens to be $\exp(-\pi |t|)$. Thus, $y(t) = \exp(-\pi t^2)$
whose Fourier transform happens to be $\exp(-\pi f^2)$. This matches
what the OP wants: the "function $x(t^2)$ has Fourier transform
that is a function of $f^2$."

But now, let's turn the problem around. We are *not told* what
the function $x(t)$ is, but we do know that $y(t) = x(t^2)$
happens to equal $\exp(-\pi t^2)$.  How can we deduce that
$x(t) = \exp(-\pi |t|)$?  *We can't* because if $x(t)$ were
chosen to be $\exp(-\pi t)$ for which the prescription is

> > take <strike>the absolute value of</strike> whatever is inside the parentheses, multiply it
> >     by $-\pi$ and raise $e$ to the result of the multiplication.

then $x(t^2) = \exp(-\pi t^2)$ also. So, did our $y(t) = \exp(-\pi t^2)$
come from $x(t) = \exp(-\pi |t|)$ or $x(t) = \exp(-\pi t)$?

In short, asking about the Fourier transform of $x(bt^2)$ is futile
unless you specify what you mean by $x(t)$.